# Array not being populated as expected in iOS project

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios

I have an iOS project that has some mp3 files in its Resources folder :
[image]

I would like to add them to an array.

The following would appear to be the appropriate way to add the mp3's to an array, but when I list the array's contents it is empty? Not sure what I am missing:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Resources"];
```

Running the following indicates the array is empty:

```
NSLog(@"Array contents: %@", myArray);
```

or

```
NSLog (@"Number of elements in array = %i", [myArray count]);
```

Comment: Are you sure there actually is a folder named "Resources" inside your application bundle ? It seems this is only a "group" : a virtual folder made up into XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn’t the problem simply the fact that the `Resources` folder is considered the root of the bundle? Did you try the same thing with `.` or something similar as the directory name?

Answer (score 3):

The Resources directory in XCode is not where your files end up on the device. They are placed in the top level of the Application Library Directory. You can use this function to get the path:

```
NSString *libDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can also just use

```
NSArray *files = [[NSBundle bundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:nil];
```